# How to export the random text generated by lipsum to txt file?

Tags: text, export, random

I'm working on a project for words manipulation. I would like to take advantage of some Latex packages `lipsum` or `blindtext` to export the output to txt file. Is this task possible? Google failed me with the search or I'm not using the right search keywords.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

%Write the output to txt file.
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: They're already just text files. It seems a weird thing to do. Why do you need this text in particular? And it is hardly `random`.

Comment: @cfr, I know but I don't want to copy and paste if this is what you mean by *they are just text files*.

Comment: You can use http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/ to create txt files as you need them ...

Comment: You can download as many books as you want in `.txt` format, which will not include markup for LaTeX. These probably include the sources for at least `kantlipsum`, if not the others. I don't understand why you'd have a bee in your bonnet about these particular texts. If you need Latin rather than English, there are plenty of Latin texts, too.

Comment: Where does the randomness come into it? Why can't you create the file online and then just save it? (If that's the way you want to do it.) `\lipsum[1]` always gives you the same output, as far as I know.

Comment: @cfr, I may use *dummy* rather than *random* but I thought it was clear from the context. Online solutions are perfect but if there is an off-line solution, it will be great.  I'm still curious though if I can do it from Latex.

Comment: @CroCo: Are you only interested in single paragraphs from [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/lipsum), as in `\lipsum[5]` or `\lipsum[10]`, not ranges like `\lipsum[5-20]`?

Comment: @Werner, yes solely single paragraphs.

Comment: @CroCo: How about [this](https://pastebin.com/JFt6V7bV)?

Comment: @Werner, precisely. Thank you. Please convert the comment to an answer.

Comment: Are you using Windows? That's the only reason I can think to do this.

Comment: @cfr, I use both Windows and Mac.

Comment: But you surely wouldn't do it this way on a *Mac*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For writing singular [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) paragraphs, you can use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

test

\makeatletter
\newwrite\lipsumoutput
\immediate\openout\lipsumoutput=\jobname.txt
\def\par{}% Remove \par from output
\immediate\write\lipsumoutput{\csname lipsum@\@roman{10}\endcsname}% Write \lipsum[10]
\immediate\closeout\lipsumoutput
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

`\lipsum[<x>]` is stored in `\lipsum@<y>` where `<y>` is the roman numeral for `<x>`.